# Why dropdown item width is larger than spinner width in android?

Tags: android, android-listview, android-spinner

I have developed a custom spinner but my spinner dropdown item is showing larger than spinner background. It is very embarrassing for users. I tried many things but I can't figure out what is the problem behind this. Could anyone help me regarding this issue. Here is the spinner and dropdown list item layout.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/title"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight=".36"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spinner_title_padding_left"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/spinner_title_padding_top"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spinner_tittle_padding_bottom"
        android:maxLength="@integer/spinner_title_max_length"
        android:singleLine="true" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@android:id/text1"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".64"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/spinner_text_padding_right"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/spinner_title_padding_left"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/spinner_text_padding_top"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/spinner_text_padding_bottom"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:maxLength="@integer/spinner_text_max_length"
        android:ellipsize="end"
        android:singleLine="true" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Here is the output [image]

Answer (score 0):

Try to use `wrap_content` instead of `match_parent` in the`LinearLayout`

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    ---

</LinearLayout>
```

This is because the items in your list don't fit on one line. Since you are setting the widths of the 2 sub views by weight and using a wrap_content width for the parent, your drop-down items will have to expand as large as they can within your 36% x 64% conditions

Answer (score 0):

It's late but maybe useful for others. I solved by adding this to Spinner.

```
android:dropDownWidth="match_parent"
```